# Homotopy Operator on de Rham Čech complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

On page 120 of Bott and Tu, it is shown that the Euler class obtained from the de Rham Čech complex and that obtained by direct construction via the structure group of sphere bundles agree. In the course of that proof a homoptopy identity is used:

$$\delta K+ K \delta= 1$$

For a cocycle $\xi$ of course this means $\delta K \xi =\xi$ but it looks like they are using some property such that actually $K\delta \xi=\xi.$ In this case $\xi$ is the 1-form constructed in the course of obtaining the global angular form. It is in the middle of page 120. I do not get why that is.

pp 120, line ~ 12 "We may take ξ
to be 1/(2π)Kdϕ." Is the crux of the matter. I do not see why.

Comment: Can you say exactly which step of the calculation you are puzzled about? (Probably you have given enough information to identify it, but I'm having trouble seeing it without reviewing a whole lot of earlier material in the book.)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I do my best; it would require several pages to go from this simple question to an actual book independent question. (maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf) 

$K\delta$ operator is claimed to be identity. $\delta$ takes the $\xi$ (sort standing for local angular forms ) and takes differences of local covers, sort of bundle angular coordinate change of variables. On the complex, K, constructs the forms from the intersection back to the forms by partition of unity. pp94 and middle of pp 120. These do not seem to combine to give identity; not at level of forms at least.

Comment: Sorry, you misinterpreted my question.  I have the book; my question is what exact line of the proof you don't understand.  In particular, it seems your question is actually about the proof of equation (8.7) on pages 94-95.  Which part of that proof do you have a problem with?

Comment: pp 120, line ~ 12 "We may take $\xi$ to be $1/(2\pi) Kd\phi.$" Is the crux of the matter. I do not see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cochain $\xi$ is defined by the property that $\delta\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi}d\phi$, and any other cochain satisfying this equation can be used to define the Euler class in place of $\xi$ (cf. the Claim at the end of page 72).  Now note that $\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi}Kd\phi$ satisfies $$\delta\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi}\delta Kd\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}(1-K\delta)d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}d\phi-K\delta d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}d\phi,$$ with the last equality being because $d\phi$ is a cocycle so $\delta d\phi=0$.  (This calculation is essentially what the second paragraph on page 95 is talking about, with $d\phi$ in place of what is called $\phi$ there.)  Thus we can take $\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi}Kd\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. That $\xi$ can be any form with that key property was what I was missing. Bottom of page 72 for others reading this.